# Missing form parameters in Compojure POST request

Tags: clojure, compojure

I'm having problems getting the form parameters in the following Compojure example:

```
(ns hello-world
  (:use compojure.core, ring.adapter.jetty)
  (:require [compojure.route :as route]))

(defn view-form []
(str "<html><head></head><body>"
   "<form method=\"post\">"
   "Title <input type=\"text\" name=\"title\"/>"
   "<input type=\"submit\"/>"
   "</form></body></html>"))

(defroutes main-routes
  (GET "/" [] "Hello World")
  (GET "/new" [] (view-form))
  (POST "/new" {params :params} (prn "params:" params))
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(run-jetty main-routes {:port 8088})
```

When submitting the form the output is always

```
params: {}
```

and I can't figure out why the title parameter is not in the params map.

I'm using Compojure 0.6.2.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have you taken into account this:

> As of version 0.6.0, Compojure no longer adds default middleware to routes. This means you must explicitly add the wrap-params and wrap-cookies middleware to your routes.

Source: https://github.com/weavejester/compojure

I tried your example with my current setup and it worked. I have included the following: `require [compojure.handler :as handler]` and `(handler/api routes)`.

Comment: `compojure.handler` is deprecated. Use `ring.middleware.params` instead.

Comment: correct, and this answer gives an example that worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8199332/3884713

Answer (score 16):

This is a great example of how to handle parameters

```
(ns example2
  (:use [ring.adapter.jetty             :only [run-jetty]]
    [compojure.core                 :only [defroutes GET POST]]
    [ring.middleware.params         :only [wrap-params]]))

(defroutes routes
  (POST "/" [name] (str "Thanks " name))
  (GET  "/" [] "<form method='post' action='/'> What's your name? <input type='text' name='name' /><input type='submit' /></form>"))

(def app (wrap-params routes))

(run-jetty app {:port 8080})
```

https://github.com/heow/compojure-cookies-example

See under Example 2 - Middleware is Features

Answer (score 0):

You can just give a list of parameters; compojure will automatically get them out of POST/GET params accordingly. If you need to do more complex stuff you can, but I've never looked into how. For example, here's a snippet from the code for [4clojure](https://4clojure.com):

```
(POST "/problems/submit" [title tags description code]
  (create-problem title tags description code))
```

Comment: I also tried it this way, but I only get nil for the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

here is a runnable example as of 17 Nov 2012:

- https://github.com/dustingetz/sandbox/tree/master/clojure/compojure-bootstrap

Comment: I followed your link and I only see a GET route, while this question is about form parameters from a POST request.