# Parsing search results from website, compojure/clojure

Tags: parsing, search, dictionary, clojure, imdb

For some time I'm working on a simple clojure project for movies, so I'm trying to parse search results from a particular web site, in my case imdb.com. Not sure If I'm on the right track for this so I'm hoping someone would help me out.

Homepage will look simple enough, with text-field where you would enter movie name and submit button named "Search". I'll try to be as much deatailed as possible:

1.This is the main page:

```
(defn view-input [] 
(view-layout 
[:h2 "Find your Movie"] 
[:body {:style "font: 14pt/16pt helvetica; background-color: #F2FB78; padding-top:100px; text-align: center"  }
(form-to [:post "/"]
  [:br] 
  [:br]
  (text-field {:placeholder "Enter movie name" } :a) [:br] 
  (submit-button "Search")
     )]
     ))
```

2.These are the functions that I've been using:

```
(defn create-flick-url [a]   
(str "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?title=" a "&title_type=feature"         
   ))


(defn flick-vec [categories a]
       (vec (let [flick-url (create-flick-url a)
                 flick-names (print-flick-name-content flick-url)]
                 (mapper-gen4 flick-names
                 (get-image-content flick-url) 
                  ))) )

(defn view-output2 [categories a]    
(view-layout
[:h2 "Search results"]
[:form {:method "post" :action "/"}               
  (interleave
    (for [flick (flick-vec categories a)]        
    (label :title (:name flick))) 
    (for [flick-name (flick-vec categories a)]        
    [:br])         
    (for [flick-image (flick-vec categories a)]
       [:img {:src (:image flick-image)}])
    (for [flick (flick-vec categories a)]
      [:br]))
      ]))
```

3.And this is the GET/POST part in the same class, where I'm using the view-output and view-output2 functions :

```
 (defroutes main-routes            
      (GET "/" [] 
        (view-input))

  (POST "/" [categories a] 
     (view-output2 categories a))
```

4.Also, these are the functions that previous ones are using:

```
(defn print-flick-name-content
 [url]
 (vec (flatten (map :content (h3+table url)))))

  (defn get-image-content
  [url]
   (vec (flatten (map #(re-find #"http.*jpg" %) 
     (map :style (map :attrs (h3+table2 url)))))))

 (defn get-page
   "Gets the html page from passed url"
  [url]
  (html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url)))

  (defn h3+table
   "Return seq of <h3> and table tags, where content of the <h3> tag meet defined condition"
  [url]
  (html/select (get-page url) 
         [:td (html/attr= :class "title") :h3 :a]))     

  (defn h3+table2
   "Return seq of <h3> and table tags, where content of the <h3> tag meet defined condition"
   [url]
   (html/select (get-page url) 
         [:td (html/attr= :class "image")]))
```

5.And here's the last one, function defined in another class which deals with map:

```
   (defn mapper-gen4
    [names images] (sort-by :name (map #(hash-map 
                            :name %1 :image %2) names images)))
```

I know it's a bit much, but this way someone will see where the problem is, so far the Search result page shows no results, nor errors, only blank page with h2 Search Results title. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As currently written, this question requires far too much investment from potential answerers.

Answer (score 0):

I would start at the form handling route:

```
(POST "/" [categories a] 
     (view-output2 categories a))
```

inserting a humble print statement:

```
(POST "/" [categories a] 
     (do
       (println "CAT" categories "A" a)
       (view-output2 categories a)))
```

Make sure your handler includes [wrap-reload](http://mmcgrana.github.io/2010/03/clojure-web-development-ring.html) so you can refresh the page and check the console. You might see that categories and a are nil, in which case you might next try something like this:

```
(POST "/" req 
     (do
       (println "REQ" req)
       (view-output2 *hard-coded-categories* *hard-coded-a*)))
```

Replace *hard-coded-categories* and *hard-coded-a* with the data structure you are expecting to see. This will test:

1. You will see in the request where the parameters are.
2. You will see whether your rendering code does what you expect with the right data.

If indeed the problem is that categories and a are nil, it might just be that you forgot a middleware handler [(see why this matters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036733/missing-form-parameters-in-compojure-post-request).

If they contain the data you expect in the structure you expect, then it is time to drill down into your other functions. For this I recommend using a REPL session and calling your top level function with the hard-coded values you are expecting from the form, however if you are using wrap-reload you could also just resubmit the form. For example you could add printouts of the inputs and outputs of your mapper-gen4 function and get-page function.

Finally after playing with some values and results, copy these from your REPL into a test file so that you have some permanent assertions about how your code behaves.

If all else fails, posting a link to your github project will get you better help - or if it is private, create a minimal example project so that people can help you more precisely.

Comment: Ok, only categories are nil, "a" is working as intended. Just wanted to ask, since I'm new to this language, what do you mean by "hard-coded"? Can you give me an example? Since the result of these functions should be a page with list of movie names and their corresponding images from the imdb. Thanks in advance

Comment: Great! Seeing you didn't pass any categories in, you don't get any output. When I say "hard-coded" I mean test data based upon your expectations of the inputs to your functions, for example if I wanted to test the (inc) function I would pass it a value of 1. In your case what you expect the categories argument data to look like.

Comment: Upon further attempts with different values of *hard-coded-categories* and *hard-coded-a*, the search result page should show soemthing, even though categories are nil, since category variable is only for genre checkboxes. I'm planning on erasing that part of code to avoid any further problems. The issue now is with get-image-content func, which is using h3+table2 func, I'm not sure if I'm using the right html/attr to parse that part of imdb site. Either way, I really appreciate your help Timothy!

Comment: I've upload project on GitHub, hope I uploaded everything, since I'm using it for the first time: [movie-search-compojure](https://github.com/vombat89/movie-search-compojure) like I said before problem must be somewhere in view-output2 part. Really appreciate if anyone could help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your current definition of image+search returns no results when passed "http://www.rottentomatoes.com/search/?search=ghost"
Your enlive selectors don't seem to be correct. Instead maybe you want something like: (map #(get-in % [:attrs :src])
       (html/select (get-page url) 
                    [:span.movieposter :img]))   which if you use the same url give a sequence of image urls as the result.  If there is something specific blocking you, please ask - in general I recommend testing your functions.

Comment: Well yeah, since I'm really new at this I presumed I messed up at enlive selectors. Gonna try know your suggestion! Thanks a million Timothy!

Comment: So using your suggestion I managed to make it work here, as well as making a sequance of links to each movie review from the search. Which is great! Now I'm hoping to display those links like a readable list. Like http//first link, [:br] , http//second link and so on...Any ideas?

Comment: Cool! If you have a sequence of links you can convert them to HTML in many ways: (interpose [:br] links)   where links is (for [u links] [:a {:href u} u])

Comment: Ok, I managed to work that out also! Thanks again! Now, I'm trying to create a link to each movie review next to each corresponding image, unlike images on rottentomatoes, links to review dont contain full link only /m/"some movie" part and i'm trying to join that part with rottentomatoes.com link. Problem is that i get a sequence of "Read here" links that navigate user to localhost:3000/m/"some movie"...

Comment: Perhaps use str to prepend the site name in front of the relative link?
[:a {:href (str "//www.rottentomatoes.com" relative-link)} title]

Comment: In the meantime I managed to find a workaround using jquery, but now I see it can be easily done with your suggestion. Thanks a lot!